# change a cell's color based on a value of several cells

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online

[image: Example of Table columns to colour code]

I have a table where by I want to colour code column names "WIS Completed" depending on whether status of facilities (Data Modelling, Data Logistics, RPT, NC, Paint, Trim, Composites and Model Shop( is "Pending" "Problem" "WIP" "Accepted" "Completed" etc.

Ultimately
If 1 status is “Stopped”, “Problem” or “Rejected” Cell “WIS Completed” is to be RED

If no status' are “Stopped”, “Problem” or “Rejected” but 1 status is “Accepted”, “Pending” or “WIP” Cell “WIS Completed” is to be YELLOW

If no status “Stopped”, “Problem”, “Rejected”, Accepted”, “Pending” or “WIP” and 1 status is “Completed” Cell “WIS Completed” to be GREEN

Answer (score 1):

Use a Calculated Column `StatusColor` to built your logic and determine a Color

Then either

- use some **25** lines of SP2013 *Client Side Rendering* JavaScript code
  to color the rows based on the calculation

  Examples: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-JS-2ed3538a

  You can determine the color within the script file; but that requires (more) editting for any future changes.
- or stuff the HTML/JavaScript in a second Calculated column (set to datatype=Number)
  to Color the row with **2** lines of JavaScript

  ```
  ="<img src=""/_layouts/images/blank.gif"" onload=""{"
      &"var TR=this;while(TR.tagName!='TR'){TR=TR.parentNode}"                
      &"TR.style.backgroundColor='" 
   &[StatusColor]
      &"';"
   &"}"">"
  ```

More *Pros & Cons* of this at: http://www.viewmaster365.com/#/How

Comment: Javascript link: http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2013/04/04/color-code-list-items-with-javascript-using-js-link-in-sharepoint-2013/

Comment: @Patrick, that CSR example creates a whole new HTML structure instead of using the existing Table. So you loose .. I better say destroy.. all the sorting, selecting, every SharePoint does for you.